# Is "close" in this sentence an adjective or an adverb?

Tags: adjectives, predicative-complement

The sentence is the following.

> "We came close to landing the deal, but the contractor turned us down at the last minute."

I would like to know whether "close" in that sentence is an adjective or an adverb.
If you give some explanation about why, that would be so much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Close*, with its complement *to landing the deal*, acts here as a **predicative complement** to the verb *come*. It is thus 'predicated of' the subject *We*, and may most conveniently be understood to be of its normal word class, an **adjective**.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence can be simplified to:

```
"We came close"
```

We is a noun, came is a verb and close is an adverb. Close describes how we came.